# Sails.js not applying model scheme when using MongoDB

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, sails.js, nosql

I'm going through the (excellent) [Sails.js book](https://www.manning.com/books/sails-js-in-action), which discusses creating a User model `User.js` in Chapter 6 like so:

```
module.exports = {
    connection: "needaword_postgresql",
    migrate: 'drop',
    attributes: {
        email: { 
            type: 'string',
            email: "true",
            unique: 'string'
        },

        username: {
            type: 'string',
            unique: 'string'
        },

        encryptedPassword: { 
            type: 'string'
        },

        gravatarURL: { 
            type: 'string'
        },

        deleted: {
            type: 'boolean'
        },

        admin: {
            type: 'boolean'
        },

        banned: {
            type: 'boolean'
        }
    },
    toJSON: function() { 
      var modelAttributes  = this.toObject();
      delete modelAttributes.password;
      delete modelAttributes.confirmation;
      delete modelAttributes.encryptedPassword;
      return modelAttributes;
    }   
};
```

Using Postgres, a new record correctly populates the boolean fields not submitted by the login form as null, as the book suggests should be the case:

[image]

But I want to use MongoDB instead of PostgreSQL. I had no problem switching the adaptor. But now, when I create a new record, it appears to ignore the schema in `User.js` and just put the literal POST data into the DB:

[image]

I understand that MongoDB is NoSQL and can take any parameters, but I was under the impression that using a schema in `Users.js` would apply to a POST request to the `/user` endpoint (via the blueprint routes for now) regardless of what database was sitting at the bottom. Do I need to somehow explicitly tie the model to the endpoint for NoSQL databases?

(I've checked the records that are created in Postgres and MongoDB, and they match the responses from localhost:1337/user posted above)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I understand that MongoDB is NoSQL

Good! In sails the sails-mongo waterline module is responsible for everything regarding mongodb. I think I found the relevant code: https://github.com/balderdashy/sails-mongo/blob/master/lib/document.js#L95 So sails-mongo simply does not care about non existent values. If you think this is bad then feel free to create an issue on the github page.

A possible workaround might be using defaultsTo:

```
banned : {
    type : "boolean",
    defaultsTo : false
}
```

Comment: Gotcha! I might raise an issue since it shouldn't be storing unencrypted passwords, but I'll stick with SQL for now. Thanks!

Comment: (Though that said, Ch7 of the book deals with some backend validation that solves some of this, so I perhaps spoke too soon. But I do still think the schema should be applied regardless of database!)

Comment: Also http://sailsjs.org/documentation/concepts/models-and-orm/lifecycle-callbacks might be worth a look, especially the callbacks on create. You can delete/encrypt them *before* they are stored in the DB. Also, decisions on database types should not depend on those kind of questions...

Answer (score 1):

You can configure your model to strictly use the schema with this flag:

```
module.exports = {
  schema: true,
  attributes: {
    ...
  }
}
```

Comment: I belive that this has absolutely no effect when using sails-mongo!

Comment: How did you test it? Did you use sails-mongo? Because I just tried it and it is not working.

Comment: Yes I used sails-mongo. If schema is true it only saves the attributes (also checked it in mongo directly just to be sure). If false all the POST params get saved.

Answer (score 0):

I eventually settled on performing the validations inside my controller.

```js
// a signup form
create: async (req, res) => {
    const { name, email, password } = req.body;
    try {
      const userExists = await sails.models.user.findOne({ email });
      if (userExists) {
        throw 'That email address is already in use.';
      }
}
```